# Filtering out "false positives" from google adwords / analytics goals, to prevent ad budget being optimised incorrectly

Tags: google-ads, goals

We have a site that is using google Adwords to drive traffic.

We have our site / Adwords setup to optimise for users submitting a lead form (the lead form confirmation page is tracked as a goal). Google Adwords is set to optimise for the advertising budget for lead form conversions.

80% of people who submit the lead form are leads. But 20% are users that are not leads, typically these are cold sales emails, or people looking for a job.

My concern is that these non lead users, who fill out the lead form still get counted as leads in google Adwords eyes and worse, google Adwords could start optimising for these type of users.

Is there any way to inform google Adwords of false positives when it comes to goals achieved, for example by date / time of the goal, or by IP of the user ?

Comment: How do you identify the false leads?  Is it possible for your website to do so before firing the goal, or does it require human identification after the fact?

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to retract those conversions via Conversion Adjustments:
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7686447?hl=en

You have to pass a unique transaction ID in your conversion tracking. You can't rely on IP address or date/time